# onewire emulation in Software

Tags: arm, interface, 1-wire

Is there any full software implementation of onewire protocol ? I mean : can we have a SW that is manipulating a PIO to emulate fully the onewire protocol ? (for instance : ARM-M4 running @150MHz).

Comment: You've tagged I2C and I2S which are different and both normally aren't considered one wire, do you mean the Maxim / Dallas protocol? But in general yes you'd be able to do it in software, maybe you can add a few more details on what you're trying to interface to.

Comment: Yes - you are correct, in fact I did not find tag for onewire - and this is why I put i2c i2s eventhough not related with ow.

Answer (score 1):

some links: http://www.hacktronics.com/Tutorials/arduino-1-wire-tutorial.html
The only point is that the read/write on onewire are done through blocking function (so while performing ow access - the processor cannot do anything else).